# How to lock a file for administrator (su/sudo password-protected) access only from command line / terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, sudo, password

I have some sensitive files that I want to protect from my own impulsivity. They're in ~ (`/home`) not `/dev` or `/bin`; those files are protected by default. However, like system files in `/dev`, `/bin`, or elsewhere, I would really like to protect some system files I have installed in my home directory (`/home` or `~` on my system). I am under the impression that `a` in `chmod a[...]` stands for "all" not "admin" or "administrator". So, I am a little stuck. Is there a way to do this? The simpler the better, but willing to do some research for a complicated solution or some shell scripting answers. GUI solutions are also acceptable but not preferable. Cmd seems to be faster.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You like to leave comments, and you are trying to help, but you don't know what's going on?

Comment: *chattr +i file* will make your file immutable (unchangable)

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will do for you, but it does for me:

```
    sudo chown 0 <files or directory>
    sudo chmod 0 <files or directory>
```

If I need to remove or modify such files, I have to reset ownership and/or permissions first.